# Show InkWell Ripple with OpenContainer animation?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Working code here:

```
                  OpenContainer(
                    openBuilder: (context, action) => const SelectedProduct(),
                    closedBuilder: (context, action) => Card(),
                  ),
                  /*Positioned.fill(
                    child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            context.read<DownloadImages>().currentProduct = i;
                            context.read<DownloadImages>().notifyListeners();
                            //Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/seven');
                          },
                          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        )
                    ),
                  ),*/
```

The commented out code is what I want to achieve. Ignore the other variables I set in `onTap`, that is not my focus, but my focus is to show this `InkWell` ripple when I click on the `Card`, or while holding it in place, and only then start the `openBuilder`.

What happens is when the `InkWell` is in place, the `InkWell` overtakes the `OpenContainer` builders and only its `onTap` gets used. How do I ignore InkWell's `onTap` for instance, and only get its animation to work along with `OpenContainer`?

**Note: Both of these are within a `Stack` widget.**

---

Complete code for testing:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'
import 'package:animations/animations.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TestPage',
      home: const Products(),
    );
  }
}

class Products extends StatefulWidget {
  const Products({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Products> createState() => _ProductsState();
}

class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 15, right: 15),
            child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: [
                  OpenContainer(
                    openBuilder: (context, action) => const SelectedProduct(),
                    closedBuilder: (context, action) => Card(
                      child: Text('Test Card')
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            //Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/seven');
                          },
                          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
            ],
          )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include fill widget that will reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I will write a complete code and post it as a dart pad soon.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Please check out the code so you can test it.

Answer (score 1):

The widget priority, bottom to top for tap event. Place tappable widget at bottom and background widgets at top.

If you swap the location, it will work.

```dart
Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              //Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/seven');
            },
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      OpenContainer(
        tappable: true,
        openBuilder: (context, action) => Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
        ),
        closedBuilder: (context, action) => Card(
          child: Text('Test Card'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

##### Without `Stack`

```dart
Material(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Ink(
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Center(
          child: OpenContainer(
            // closedColor: Colors.pink, or card color
            openBuilder: (context, action) =>
                const Text("Open card"),
            closedBuilder: (context, action) =>
                Card(child: Text('Test Card')),
            // ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you, that works now, but my desired outcome is still not met. I want the `InkWell` splash effect to also play before the `OpenContainer` animation (while the user is holding his finger on the `Card`). Is there a way to get that to work?

Comment: To have the delay you can use controller to open `OpenContainer` ,also you can try with using `InkWell<SizedBox<200,200, OpenContainer>>`

Comment: How do I open the `OpenContainer`, I don't understand what you mean by controller? Is there a way to call the `closedBuilder` or do you mean something else? I tried the `SizedBox` child solution but I got some errors.

Comment: You check the update one, using `Ink`, hope it is the thing you are looking for.